# SSRS: Can I force a table to start in a new page to avoid content to be split off?

Tags: reporting-services

I've 4 table in the report on the page. A and D are really big reports with many rows. B and C are small table with one row each.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|                    Table A                  |
+---------------------------------------------+

+-------------+              +----------------+
| Table B     |              |    Table C     |
+-------------+              +----------------+

+---------------------------------------------+
|                    Table D                  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is that, depending on the number of rows in table A, table D is being in 2 pages, which the customer doesn't like. Something like:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|            Header of Table D               |
+--------------------------------------------+
|          Few rows in one page              |



|    The rest of the rows in another page    |
+--------------------------------------------+
|    Footer here                             |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to force table D to start in a new page, no matter where the rest of the content ends?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: So far, I've pushed table D further down, and it's being displayed in the second page of the report. However, I think that's cheating as if table A get way more rows or less rows then Table D will have the header followed by a couple of rows at the bottom of a page and the rest of the content at the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option when building tables, to choose to keep everything on 1 page. Just click "Tablix Properties" then under the "general" tab you can select the option "Keep together on one page if possible". Also, you can add page breaks before and after in the same section.

Answer (score 2):

Tablix Properties > General > Page Break Options

You can set it to after, before or try to keep the table on one page.